# Delete a mysql row with two variables Jquery AJAX and confirmation

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax, user-interface

I'm not even novice in javascript so you will see frankestain job from now on :P. 
I've been having a problem, tried all the solutions found here in the forum but I can't seem to get a solution..

I'm trying to delete a mysql row that has two columns atomoID and upo8ID (this table serves for multilinking the ids from other tables (clients and cases).

the variable $upo8ID is set in the page via GET ?recordID=1.

the $atomoID is a list that comes from mysql in a list (multiple records: `<?php echo $row_pelates['AA']`)

the table 'sxes-at-up' keeps the links between them (ex. atomoID = 1 and upo8ID = 1)

I want to have a delete button in every row that can delete the link between the 2 variables.

Here is what I've done so far:

the php:

```
<?php if(isset($row_pelates['AA'])) { ?>
<table> 
<tr><th>...</th></tr>
<tr><td>...<button id="button3">del</button></tr>
...</table><?php } ?>
```

the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("button#button3").click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
$("#dialog3").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:170,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "DELETE": function() {

                  var atomoID = $<?php echo $row_pelates['AA']; ?>;
                  var upo8ID = $("#upo8ID").val();
                  var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
                  $.ajax({
                  type: 'get',
                  url: 'delete.php',
                  data: { atomoID: '$atomoID', upo8ID: '$upo8ID' },
                  dataType: "json",
                  beforeSend: function() {
                     parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
                  },
                  success: function() {
                  parent.fadeOut(300,function() {
                  parent.remove();
             });
         }
     });

                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "CANCEL": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

the dialog:

```
<div id="dialog3" title="Διαγραφή επαφής" style="display: none;">
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
</div>
```

and the delete.php

```
<?php include("includes/init.php"); ?>

<?php
$atomoID = $_POST[atomoID];
$upo8ID = $_POST[upo8ID];

if (isset($_POST['atomoID'])) {    
   $query = "DELETE FROM sxes-at-up WHERE atomoID = $atomoID AND upo8ID = $upo8ID";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    echo "deleted!";
}
?>
```

I now I have many errors, but I reached my current limit with this :(
Can anyone help?

Comment: You really need to explain what the errors are if you want any hope that the question can be answered.

Comment: i need some help wrighting the "DELETE": function() { with ajax properly, what i've made is noob stuff..

Answer (score 0):

I had some errors in delete.php now it works, now my only problem is that I can't send data from an array with jquery,
example: i put

```
<?php $atomoID= $row_pelates['AA']?>
```

where 
`$row_pelates['AA']` is the array showing in a table,

but clicking on the confirmation dialog only takes the first number of the array and send its to the delete.php

is there a way to put a link in every line of the table, that will take the correct number and send it with jquery-ajax to the deletion php?